# Why is my serial read on Windows COM port limited to 8192 bytes?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, usb

I'm trying to read 20100 bytes from my COM port in windows. The data is truncated to 8192 bytes.  What gives? When I use TeraTerm, there is no truncation. My synchronous calls are:

```
CreateFile(dev, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

And (code snippet for non-overlapped read only)

```
DWORD dwEventMask, dwIncommingReadSize;
int dwSize=0;
char szBuf[10];
if(!SetCommMask((void *) fd, EV_RXCHAR)) {THIS_RTN_ERROR}

do  {
        if(ReadFile((void *) fd, szBuf, 1, &dwIncommingReadSize, NULL) != 0) {
            if(dwIncommingReadSize > 0) {
                for (k=0; k<dwIncommingReadSize; k++) {
                  *(line_buf+dwSize+k) = szBuf[k];
                }
                dwSize += dwIncommingReadSize;
            }
        }
        else {THIS_RTN_ERROR;}
    } while(dwIncommingReadSize > 0);
k = dwSize;
return(k);
```

This occurs immediately after a WriteFile. I iteratively call this code until I get all the data - except I only get 8192 bytes.

Comment: what is the definition of the array: `line_buf[]`

Comment: Is the code trying to read an array that was just written to the COM port?  What hardware is out there that actually echos the data?  Does your code check the results of the write operation to assure that all the data was written?  is the missing data from the beginning or end of the written data?

Comment: Why the cast in `(void *) fd`,  It makes me think code is doing something not yet posted that it should not.  Recommend a [mcve].

Comment: Easy one, I use fd either as a socket or a pointer, it's a long integer that needs the cast (actually just a warning without). That, I haven't had issues with. As for the nature of the data and the array, I give the command "FORM4; OUTPDATA?;" to the USB to GPIB adapter and the adapter responds with 20100 ASCII characters of formatted S-parameter data, real/imaginary pairs separated with commas and CR. Only the first 8192 bytes is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you explicitly specified 8192 as the dwInQueue parameter in the SetupComm function, or the device driver default value is 8192?

How about specifying the buffer size required by SetupComm?

[SetupComm function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setupcomm)

> Initializes the communications parameters for a specified communications device.
>   Syntax C++

```
BOOL SetupComm(  
  HANDLE hFile,  
  DWORD  dwInQueue,  
  DWORD  dwOutQueue  
);
```

> Parameters
>   hFile
>   A handle to the communications device. The CreateFile function returns this handle.
>
> dwInQueue
>   The recommended size of the device's internal input buffer, in bytes.
>
> dwOutQueue
>   The recommended size of the device's internal output buffer, in bytes.

For .NET SerialPort, the default value is 4096, up to 2147483647 can be specified.
[SerialPort.ReadBufferSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets or sets the size of the SerialPort input buffer.
>   C#

```
[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true)]  
public int ReadBufferSize { get; set; }
```

> Property Value
>   Int32
>   The buffer size, in bytes. The default value is 4096; the maximum value is that of a positive int, or 2147483647.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer. As per the accepted answer, increasing the buffer size will fix your problem 99.9% of the time.

But the the serial interface (like the socket) is just a stream of bytes. So one always has to deal with two opposing problems:

- partial messages
- multiple messages

Worse, you can get a complete message followed by a truncated message.

The standard way of handling this, in both Unix and Windows, is to use `select`. See, for example, https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/.

The resulting code is not long, but you need to know what you want to it do.

---

**Edit**: On Windows, `select` only works with sockets. Maybe [Batch-File: Receive Data from the Serial-Port and write it into txt-File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489733/batch-file-receive-data-from-the-serial-port-and-write-it-into-txt-file) would help?

Comment: Exactly, I know all about Select() and use it often. I use it for Windows/Linux TCP sockets and Linux serial communications. Not having it in Windows serial comm is why I had to rewrite the code in the first place.